# ExeShield with .Net dialog app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

does anyone have any samples using ExeShield with VS 2010 c++ winforms app? I followed the directions and tutorial video and ExeShield splash screen displays, but when I press the "try" button, the splash screen disappears, but my app does not run.
Thank you for any help/
Bill

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from ExeShield tech support, listed below:

Here are a few things to look at.

1. Make sure you compile for x86 and not x64
2. Use .NET 3.5 or lower.

These settings are needed for C++ apps

Linker
Randomized Base Address: Disable Image Randomization (/DYNAMICBASE:NO)
Image is not compatible with DEP (/NXCOMPAT:NO)
Under "Optimization" Set "Link Time Code Generation" to "Use Link Time Code Generation (/ltcg)